# How do I create diagrams with boxes and arrows in LaTeX using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tikz-arrows

[image: Box_and_arrays]

I would like to create a diagram like the picture above using TikZ. I have very little idea about TikZ since I have never used it before. I would like to create a diagram to demonstrate shallow copy and deep copy in C++ as a part of my assignment (The picture above does not demonstrate this, but this is how I would approach the problem). How would I draw such boxes and arrows like the diagram above? Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
\node (n1) [draw, minimum width=4em] {Bar};
\draw[<-, shorten <=1mm] 
    (n1.south west) -- ++ (-1,-0.5) node [below, align=center] {B\\ (note)};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I place a node above another one like the left portion of my figure? And why the way I tried is not working as I expected? `\node (n1) [draw, minimum width=4em] {\texttt{1920}};
\node (n1) [draw, minimum width=4em] at (n1.north west){\texttt{1920}};`

Comment: Nvm, this seemed to work for me: `\node (n1) [draw, minimum width=4em] {\texttt{1920}};
\node (n2) [draw, minimum width=4em, above =of n1] {\texttt{1920}};`.